# run yz tasks only if x task condition is met in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Team,
I have 10 tasks and I want to run 2-10 only if condition in task1 is met.

```
- name: 1Check if the node needs to be processed
  stat: /tmp/fscache-cleaned-up1.log
  register: dc_status
```

```
- name: 2Check if the node needs to be processed
  stat: /tmp/fscache-cleaned-up2.log
  register: dc_status
  failed_when: dc_status.stat.exists
```

..
..
..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use "path" in your stat module call and "block" for combining dependant tasks, like this:

```
- name: Check if the node needs to be processed
  stat:
    path: /tmp/fscache-cleaned-up1.log
  register: dc_status

- name: Run this only when the log file exists
  block:
    - name: Install something
      yum:
        name:
        - somepackage
        state: present

     - name: Apply a config template
      template:
        src: templates/src.j2
        dest: /etc/foo.conf

    - name: Start a service and enable it
      service:
        name: bar
        state: started
        enabled: True
  when: 
    - dc_status.stat.exists
    - dc_status.stat.is_file
```

Additional information: [ansible stat module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/stat_module.html), [block usage](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html)